# Unix variable usage

Tags: bash, unix

If I have 2 variables with values assigned as below -

```
a=1; s1=555
```

Can we print 555 using:

```
$ echo $s`echo $a`
```

...? My requirement is use variable 'a' in second variable to print final value of s1.

I have tried it already and failed. Is there any way?

Thanks.

Comment: Which shell, *specifically*? There are better answers available for ksh or bash than POSIX sh.

Comment: ...btw, this is the topic of BashFAQ #6: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables

Comment: Thank you. The link was helpful.

Comment: Then your question should be tagged `bash`.

Comment: In Bash, `v="s${a}"; echo ${!v}`.  The old way is `eval echo "\$s$a"`, but isn't recommended if you have an alternative (`eval` is dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

Bash has native syntax for indirect evaluation support:

```
a=1
s1=555

varname="s$a"
echo "${!varname}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It worked. :-)